# error when getting VBScript (Classic ASP) Dictionary Object values dynamically on 2nd iteration of a For...Each loop

Tags: arrays, dictionary, asp-classic, vbscript, loops

Yeah, its a long and convoluted title... sorry.

I am working in VBScript in good ol' fashioned ASP.  I've got a dictionary object, and each object in the dictionary consists of it's Key, and an Array as the Item.

```
Dim myDictionary
Set myDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

myDictionary.Add "a", Array("a1","a2")
myDictionary.Add "b", Array("b1","b2")
myDictionary.Add "c", Array("c1","c2")
```

I am also passing into the script a list of strings (and converting to an array), that correspond with various dictionary entries, so that only those entries may be displayed on the page, and in the order of the array.

```
Dim myText
myText = "a, b, c"

Dim myArray
myArray = Split(myText,",")
```

Now, I want to iterate through the array, and show the contents of each corresponding Key in myDictionary.

```
For Each thing in myArray
    Response.Write myDictionary.Item(thing)(0) & "&nbsp;" & myDictionary.Item(thing)(1) & "<br />" & vbcrlf
Next
```

It works perfectly in the first Iteration, and properly prints to the page.  But on the 2nd iteration, I get an error.  Here's the full output on the page:

> a1 a2
>
> Microsoft VBScript runtime error
>
> '800a000d' Type mismatch: 'Item(...)'
>
> /Alpine/en_us/testCase.asp, line 28

Anyone know why this doesn't work?  Naturally, the code shown here is just a test-case, but I am having the exact same problem in my application.

Here is the complete code, so you can just cut-n-paste it into your test environment, if it helps you help me figure this one out:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Iterating through Dictionary objects - Test Case</title>
</head>

<body>

<%


Dim myDictionary
Set myDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

myDictionary.Add "a", Array("a1","a2")
myDictionary.Add "b", Array("b1","b2")
myDictionary.Add "c", Array("c1","c2")

Dim myText
myText = "a, b, c"

Dim myArray
myArray = Split(myText,",")

For Each thing in myArray
    Response.Write myDictionary.Item(thing)(0) & "&nbsp;" & myDictionary.Item(thing)(1) & "<br />" & vbcrlf
Next

%>


</body>
</html>
```

Some other interesting bits about this problem...

When I hard-code all three dictionary entries within the iterations, it works fine:

```
For Each thing in myArray
    Response.Write myDictionary.Item("a")(0) & "&nbsp;" & myDictionary.Item("a")(1) & "<br />" & vbcrlf
    Response.Write myDictionary.Item("b")(0) & "&nbsp;" & myDictionary.Item("b")(1) & "<br />" & vbcrlf
    Response.Write myDictionary.Item("c")(0) & "&nbsp;" & myDictionary.Item("c")(1) & "<br />" & vbcrlf
Next
```

Produces this:

> a1 a2
>   b1 b2
>   c1 c2
>   a1 a2
>   b1 b2
>   c1 c2
>   a1 a2
>   b1 b2
>   c1 c2

And to verify that the 'thing' variable in the For-Each loop works:

```
For Each thing in myArray
    Response.Write thing
Next
```

Produces this:

> a b c

I'm confused...

Thanks everyone!  I really appreciate any help you can provide.  :-)

Cheers,
Lelando

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have spaces after your commas in `myText`. The Split function creates an array with the values `"a", " b", " c"`. The second two values don't exist in your Dictionary.

Replace the line

```
myText = "a, b, c"
```

With

```
myText = "a,b,c"
```

Or change your token delimiter with `", "` (note the space).

Comment: Well, that did it!  Since all of my possible Key terms are single words, and I know that the people who will be creating the comma-delimited list will be using spaces *inconsistently*, I will have to also remove all spaces from the list first, I think.  Sound right to you?

Comment: Sounds fine to me. Just use myText = Replace(myText, " ", "")